# delete row with ajax function and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have a table with mysql Data,i add a trash button and i want remove each row when trash button is clicked with ajax function,
this is my html:

```
  <table border="1">
    <?php
$sql ="SELECT * FROM music";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){

    echo '<tr><td>'.$row->file_name.'</td><td>'.$row->composer.'</td><td>'.$row->lyric.'</td><td>'.$row->music_thumb.'</td><td>'.'

    <a href="#" id="'.$row->msuic_id.'" class="trash" >
    جذف کردن
    </a>

    '.'</td></tr>';
    }

?>
  </table>
```

and my ajax function here:

```
$(function(){
        $('.trash').click(function(){
            var del_id= $(this).attr('id');
            var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:del_id,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="YES"){
                        $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                        }else{
                            alert("can't delete the row")
                            }
                    }

                })
            })
    });
```

and also my "delete.php" page here:

```
<?php
include('../db_inc.php');
$music_number = "POST['del_id']";
echo '$music_number';
$qry = "DELETE FROM music WHERE msuic_id ='$music_number'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

?>
```

i think my problem is ajax function;
thanks

Comment: Check for any errors in your browser console..

Comment: Change to $music_number = $_POST['del_id'];

Comment: There is more than one problem, and all solutions have already been given :) : 1° replace `"POST['del_id']"` by `$_POST['del_id']` ,2° replace `data:del_id` by `data:{del_id:del_id}` (notice the 1st is a parameter name, and the second is the variable). And you should consider to use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_` functions which are deprecated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'delete.php',
    data:{del_id:del_id},
    success: function(data){
         if(data=="YES"){
             $ele.fadeOut().remove();
         }else{
             alert("can't delete the row")
         }
    }

     })
})
```

and also change

```
$music_number = "POST['del_id']";
```

to

```
$music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Your ajax code should be this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.trash',function(){
        var del_id= $(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete.php',
            data:{'del_id':del_id},
            success: function(data){
                 if(data=="YES"){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                 }else{
                        alert("can't delete the row")
                 }
             }

            });
        });
});
```

And PHP code should be:

```
<?php
include('../db_inc.php');
$music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
//echo $music_number;
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM music WHERE msuic_id=?");
$stmt->execute([$music_number]);
echo "YES";
```

Comment: thanks, your code is work but every time i click on trash,show alert:"can't delete the row" but when i reload the page i see the row is deleted,what's the problem?

Comment: @Radian I have updated the code. check that. this is due to you are checking the value **YES** and in php file it was **yes**. so I have updated the answer. if this will help then mark it as accepted.

Comment: oh i find the problem, i should change the "YES" to  if(data==del_id+"YES"), thanks much, please update your code :)

Comment: @Radian which code you have used. use the PHP code. and in success function try to check what is coming. by `alert(data);`.

Comment: i check that and alert = 18YES ---> 18 refer to row id, i just copy and paste your code,

Comment: @Radian sorry my mistake now I have update it. Here it is echoing `echo $music_number;` also in PHP file so need to comment it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above answers, you should delegate your on click handler to prevent unnecessary duplication

```
$(document).on('click', '.trash', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$music_number = POST['del_id']; in delete.php

write ajax function like:

$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:del_id,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="YES"){
                        $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                        }else{
                            alert("can't delete the row")
                            }
                    }

                })
            });
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things that you need to correct

- In "delete.php" file
  `$music_number = "POST['del_id']";
  // to 
  $music_number = $_POST['del_id'];`

  Also, in the success callback of ajax, you are checking for "YES" in response which is not sent anywhere in this file.
- Change to your ajax request

  `data: {'del_id':del_id},`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

send you data as object and not just value

```
 ...
 type:'POST',
 url:'delete.php', 
 data:{'del_id':del_id},  //<----here
 ....
```

and take it as POST in delete.php

```
 $music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
```

**updated**

add this to your delete.php

```
<?php
 include('../db_inc.php');
 $music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
  $qry = "DELETE FROM music WHERE msuic_id ='$music_number'";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);
  if($result) {
      echo "Yes";
   } else {
      echo "No";
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks, your code is work but every time i click on trash,show alert:"can't delete the row" but when i reload the page i see the row is deleted,what's the problem?

Comment: i get error as Notice: Undefined index: del_id on php line :  $music_number = "POST['del_id']";

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'delete.php',
    data:{del_id:del_id},
    success: function(data){
         if(data=="YES"){
             $ele.fadeOut().remove();
         }else{
             alert("can't delete the row")
         }
    }

     })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).