# Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined?

Tags: php, angularjs

im building a project with angular and php and im trying to delete a row from database table. i don't know what to do with this error can someone help please? this is my code

php for retrieve- get-allCustomers.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');
  if(!$con){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }
  $query = "SELECT `customer_id`, `kind_Of_Customer`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `id`, `city` FROM `customers`";
  $result = $con->query($query);
  $r = array();
  if( $result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $r[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $res = json_encode($r);
   echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

html code for retrieveing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head >

</head>
<body>
    <h2>כרטיסי לקוחות</h2>
    <!-- <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCardDetails">לחץ לפרטי כרטיס לקוח</a> -->

    <div class="search">
       <label>חיפוש:</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="search_query">
       <label>מיון לפי:</label>
       <select ng-model="order_query">
           <option value="kind_Of_Customer" >סוג לקוח</option>
           <option value="first_name">שם</option>
           <option value="id">ת"ז</option>
       </select>
       <label>מיון הפוך:</label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="reverse_query" value="reverse" >
   </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table  class="customer-list table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- <th>#</th> -->
            <th class="Column-Header">מספר לקוח</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">סוג לקוח</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">שם פרטי</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">שם משפחה</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">ת.ז</th>
            <th class="Column-Header">עיר</th>
            <!-- <th>כתובת</th> -->
            <!-- <th>מס' טלפון</th> -->
            <!-- <th>מס' טלפון 2</th> -->
            <!-- <th>אימייל</th> -->
            <!-- <th>פקס</th> -->
            <!-- <th>הופנה דרך</th> -->
            <!-- <th>הערות</th> -->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in customers | filter:search_query | orderBy: order_query:reverse_query">
            <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.last_name }}</td>
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.city}} </td>
            <td><button ng-click="delete(customers.customer_id, $index)">Delete</button><td>
            <!-- <td> {{ x.address}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.phone}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.phone_2}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.email}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.fax}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.referrer}} </td> -->
            <!-- <td> {{ x.comments}} </td> -->
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

php - deleteCustomer.php :

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hamatkin');

  if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
     $id=$_GET['customer_id'];
     $del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id='".$id."'";
     mysqli_query($connect,$del);
  }
?>
```

controller - this controller get all customers table data and showing it. it works fine. the rest is what i tried for delete.:

```
"use strict";

angular.module('dataSystem').controller('customerCardsCtrl', function($scope,$route,$location,$http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/get-allCustomers.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.customers = arr;
      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('err', err)
  });

  $scope.delete = function(deletingId, index){
      var params = $.param({"customer_id":deletingId})
      $http({
        url: "api/deleteCustomer.php",
        method:"GET",
        data:params

      }).success(function(data){
        $scope.customers = data;
        $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
        console.log(data)
      });

  }
```

Comment: The error means `$scope.data` is undefined in your success function. i.e. `$scope` or `data` can't be found.

Comment: what should i dot? @BadHorsie

Comment: Just use `data` which you can see is passed through the function argument.

Comment: @BadHorsie the console is showing me: "data.splice is not a function " now

Comment: `splice()` is an Array method, so if `data` is not an array you can't use that function on it. I would check what the value of `data` is and let us know.

Comment: Does `$scope.data` contain anything? Error seems to imply it does not exist.

Comment: @apokryfos im new at this...i don't think the data contains something. what sholud  i do?

Comment: We need to see more of your code to be able to help better.

Comment: i will edit and add all my code now. thanks @mikeagoff

Comment: @mikeagoff can u take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$scope.data.splice(index, 1);` with simply `data.slice(index, 1);`

The data being returned doesn't live in $scope.

Comment: i did what u said it still doesn't work....the console is showing me: "data.splice is not a function

Comment: As @BadHorsie said above, if the data coming back is not in an Array, then you will continue to get that error.

Comment: I think the OPs intention was to remove the deleted data from the `$scope` and not work with any returned data from the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a `$scope.variable = [];` outside the scope of the function and then

```
.success(function(data){
        $scope.variable = data;
        $scope.variable.splice(index,1);
      });
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: can you make a console.log(data); right inside .success function and go in your browser's console to show us the result please.

Comment: @jean-micheal i edited the code console not showing anything, now when i press delete button it all rows dissapeard untill i refresh the page

Comment: Well the console.log(data) should return something or even undefined. Are you sure you didn't change any of the code?

Comment: @jean-michael provencher  this is what i changed            }).success(function(data){
        $scope.customers = data;
        $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
        console.log(data)
      }); you can look at the code above

Comment: remove both lines before console.log(data) and only leave console.log(data and then go in your console to show what data looks like.

Comment: @jean-michael provencher now the delete button is working after i removed @scope.customers=data; line. but when i refresh all data comes back and of course it doesn't delete in phpmyadmin

Comment: can you go in the console and show me what console.log(data) returns

Comment: it takes me to Sources and showing me this. it says a problem with the last line(}).............................................................    }).success(function(data){

            $scope.customers.splice(index,1); index=0
            console.log(data)
          });

      }

Comment: Don't go in sources go in console please

Comment: when i click delete it takes me from console to sources and when i return to console it still doesn't show anything

Comment: what do you think it is?

Comment: I have no idea, when you click on delete it should trigger your delete function and so execute the line with console.log(data); and then you should be able to go see the content of data into your console

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do in the success callback is to remove the deleted customer from the view.

Try with.

```
$scope.customers.splice(index,1);
```

in the success callback

Comment: i edited the code console not showing anything, now when i press delete button it all rows dissapeard untill i refresh the page

Comment: why are you doing this $scope.customers = data; please remove this line.

Comment: i removed that row and now its deleteing every row but when i refresh the page all the data comes back...and of course its not deleting in phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok, it seems the call you are making for delete is responding as success without actually deleting it from the server. Another issue i can see is you are trying to delete the customer using a GET call, it should be a DELETE. Could you please check  if the PHP server side code is executing properly.

Comment: i changed to DELETE but it still the same. what do you mean check php server code is executing properly?

Comment: I meant if the call is reaching "deleteCustomer.php" and executing  this code if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
     $id=$_GET['customer_id'];
     $del="DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_id='".$id."'";
     mysqli_query($connect,$del);
  }

Comment: how do i check this?

Comment: First step is to echo the value of  $_GET['customer_id'] and see if you getting this value properly.

Comment: as a help you can check the below link , he is using POST call to delete in the example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724383/delete-row-with-ajax-function-and-php